# How to position the marker to the correct position?

Tags: android, android-maps

[image]

As you can see on my screenshot, the marker is placed beside of the correct coordinate position, how to make it placed on the correct position (in the center of the circle) ?

in my code :

```
Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
icon.setBounds(0, 0, icon.getIntrinsicWidth(), icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

are the values on the setBounds() are the positions that i should change to move the marker?
i've tried it but nothing changes
so, how to fix the position?

thanks

i love stackoverflow, hehe :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, as I don't know how you are implementing it:
http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html